# What type of hash does WordPress use?

Tags: php, wordpress, hash

What type of hash does WordPress use?
Here is an example of a WordPress hash:

> $P$Bp.ZDNMM98mGNxCtHSkc1DqdRPXeoR.

Comment: Its blowfish hashing technic, you can read more from here.   http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/

Comment: It is a combined string that can include identifiers (of what's to come), salt, and the password hash. It is designed to allow for multiple hash types and backwards/forwards compatibility. In your example string, `$P$` indicates that it is salted, `B` indicates that it is hashed with Blowfish (I think), the next 8 characters (`p.ZDNMM9`) are the salt and the rest is the hash. You can see the source code for how it works [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-phpass.php).

Comment: @CollinKrawll The 'B' indicates the number of hash iterations it does, not that it is Blowfish. 'B' is the 13th element in the `itoa64` string which indicates 2^13 iterations.

Answer (score 168):

The WordPress password hasher implements the [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), which is used in Content Management Systems like WordPress and Drupal.

They used to use MD5 in the older versions, but thankfully, no more. You can generate hashes using this encryption scheme at http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php.

Comment: is someone comes across this old question like I did please note that MD5 is no longer acceptable. if you have >PHP 5.5.0 use the new `password_hash` function. if you only have >PHP 5.3.7 use the compatibility library here https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: I don't know if this will help at all, but WP will still take the straight MD5 the first time you used the Password, then it will "salt" it. SO, if you have access to the DB, using MyPHPAdmin you can change the PW to "MyPass", select MD5 in the "Function" dropdown and it will save as a straight MD5. Sign into Wordpress, and it will change it to the "salted" version with the $P$B__/ added.

Comment: Basically, if the user has NOT signed in with the PW, it will still be in MD5 format, it will look the same as anyone else with that same PW. Once you sign in, even with that SAME EXACT PW, it will change to YOUR own personal "salt", so you and your friend, sign in at the same time with the same PW, your "salted MD5" will look different. Meaning, there is no way to query the DB to test if a PW has been changed from the default, since WP will change it to a salted version, even if it was the same as the default.

Comment: @AndrewBrown,  I disagree that MD5 is no longer acceptable. May be its true for creating the pass from the CMS, but try on DB Level..it still works.To date when I loses WP password; I am login to phpMyAdmin and generate MD5 hash for password fields in wp_users table and it works... Google: [manually reset the WordPress administrator password](https://www.google.com/search?q=reset+wp+admin+password+phpmyadmin)..see also johnMetta 's answer.

Comment: @wpcoder MD5 is no questions asked, 100% cryptographically insecure, and unacceptable to use as a hashed password storage method.

Comment: What I meant @AndrewBrown is that MD5 still working with WP; didn't mean the insecure aspect. I agree with you.

Comment: Ahh. Gotcha. Just another reason I can’t stand WP

Comment: @AndrewBrown The only reason MD5 still works is to support backwards compatibility. As soon as the user signs in it will update the md5 to the new hash. But yes that does leave a security vulnerability. Its been long enough WP should stop supporting MD5

Comment: MD5-ed passwords no longer work for wp-admin logins, even for the first time after your change. You have to change them in this case in your database to the PHPass-hashed passwords.

Comment: @VadimAnisimov If the password in the DB is MD5 for a wp-admin user, it will still work (but change it to the new salted format on first login). I know, because I just changed a user password by directly inserting the MD5 in MySQL, in a new(-ish, 5.8.1) installation.

Comment: Absolutely amazing that it is 2023 and Wordpress has not done any upgrades to using phpass.php (Portable PHP hashing framework) as the default! They have added some hooks that allow plugins to override the default behavior, so that is good. Anybody like me coming here looking for a better solution should check out the plugin by Roots that changes passwords to bcrypt hashing https://github.com/roots/wp-password-bcrypt

Answer (score 24):

```
$hash_type$salt$password
```

If the hash does not use a salt, then there is no `$` sign for that. The actual hash in your case is after the 2nd `$`

The reason for this is, so you can have many types of hashes with different salts and feeds that string into a function that knows how to match it with some other value.

Comment: thanks
but i thought md5 hashes had to be in hex, like this: b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184

why does this hash have chars A-Z and . in it?
is it a md5 hash?

Comment: Could be that type of hash that is used. A Hash is just a fixed size string. Could contain anything you want.

Comment: @Amanda Kumar. Extremely late to this party, but MD5 produces a 128-bit (16-byte) value. That value can be stored and represented in different ways, for example as a hex string, a Base64 string, or raw data in a file. You commonly see MD5 values represented in hex, however WordPress uses Base64 instead. Your hex value would be sZRqySSS0jR8YjW00mERhA== in Base64, which uses 25% less characters than hex to represent the same data.

Answer (score 17):

For manually resetting the password in Wordpress DB, a simple MD5 hash is sufficient. (see reason below)

To prevent breaking backwards compatibility, MD5-hashed passwords stored in the database are still valid.  When a user logs in with such a password, WordPress detects MD5 was used, rehashes the password using the more secure method, and stores the new hash in the database.

Source: http://eamann.com/tech/wordpress-password-hashing/

Update: this was an answer posted in 2014. I don't know if it still works for the latest version of WP since I don't work with WP anymore.

Comment: Saving a MD5 hash doesn't work any more.  Source: I just tried it.

Comment: Just tried it also and logged in. The MD5 got auto-converted to a wp hash. Wp version 5.1

Comment: Just tried and it works in my WP, too. 
$wp_version = '5.5.3';
$wp_db_version = 48748;

Comment: Works in `5.8.3` as well.

Answer (score 14):

MD5 worked for me changing my database manually. See: [**Resetting Your Password**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password)

Comment: no this isn't a plain md5 hash, plain md5 hashes look like this: b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184
i've heard it's based on md5, but can someone please tell me what type of hash it uses and what option to seelect in passwordspro

Comment: MD5 will work if entered manually into the table, but upon first login WP will rewrite it using its own hash so it works great for  resetting the password but not more than that.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales - typing the PassWord as is in the DB then selecting MD5 from the drop down still works. You can also copy/paste an MD5 encrypted string into the box and not select anything and it will work 

(so, if your PW is "qwertyuiop" your ND5 is "6eea9b7ef19179a06954edd0f6c05ceb". If you use the straight "qwertyuiop" password, select "MD5", or use that long hash and don't select anything, save the DB, and then log into WordPress using "qwertyuiop" and it will work)

Answer (score 11):

It depends at least on the version of PHP that is used. `wp-includes/class-phpass.php` contains all the answers.

Comment: This class implements the - Portable PHP password hashing framework. This answer prints all you need...

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem finding out what kind of Hash does Wordpress Uses .

It is **wp hash password**.

Example

Compare an already hashed password with its plain-text string:

```
<?php
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$password_hashed = '$P$B55D6LjfHDkINU5wF.v2BuuzO0/XPk/';
$plain_password = 'test';

if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
?>
```

See These Links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/)

It uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is using WordPress class to authenticate users. Here is my solutions:

**1. Include following WordPress PHP file:**

`include_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "wp-includes" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "class-phpass.php");`

**2. Create an object of `PasswordHash` class:**

`$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);`

**3. call `CheckPassword` function to authenticate user:**

`$check = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $row['user_pass']);`

**4. check `$check` variable:**

```
if($check) {
   echo "password is correct";
} else {
   echo "password is incorrect";
}
```

Please Note that:  `$password` is the un-hashed password in clear text whereas `$row['user_pass']` is the hashed password that you need to fetch from the database.

Comment: It isn't clear in the answer but $password is the un-hashed pass in clear text whereas $row['user_pass'] is the hashed password that you need to fetch from the db yourself.

Comment: Note that you can also do that directly in the shell with `php -a` and entering the commands: `include("/path/to/.../class-phpass.php"); $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true); echo ( $wp_hasher->CheckPassword('password', 'hash_from_db') ? "OK" : "BAD), "\n";`

Answer (score 5):

Start phpMyAdmin and access wp_users from your wordpress instance.
Edit record  and select user_pass function to match MD5. Write the string that will be your new password in VALUE.
Click, GO.
Go to your wordpress website and enter your new password.
Back to phpMyAdmin you will see that WP changed the HASH to something like $P$B...
enjoy!

Comment: confirmed 2017 WP install in 2019!

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress uses **MD5** Password hashing. Creates a hash of a plain text password. Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it's supported on all platforms. You can configure PasswordHash to use Blowfish or extended DES (if available) instead of MD5 with the $portable_hashes constructor argument or property.

Answer (score 2):

include_once('../../../wp-config.php');

global $wpdb;

$password = wp_hash_password("your password");

Answer (score -1):

By default wordpress uses MD5. You can upgrade it to blowfish or extended DES.

Comment: MD5 is a simplistic way