# HOw can i get the actual password of wordpress user

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Presently i  am getting the password from database and   its giving me hash key string  how i get the actual password  of hash in text

$P$Bx0Jgq6/Qw/o3A5fXcVKg4jxQr2PAB1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Wordpress stores passwords as [one-way hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Some more info here: [What are the details behind the way Wordpress stores user authentication data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058961/what-are-the-details-behind-the-way-wordpress-stores-user-authentication-data)

Comment: so it mean i unable to get the password from database according to this only option to update ]

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant with "you can't". It's a good thing though. You (as site owner) are not **supposed** to know your user's passwords.

Comment: @VikasGautam especially from a developer's point of view. Developers can be bad guys too.

Comment: ha haaa    yes i can   reset i can remove i can update  but not able to retrieve  password from database

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/md5-password-hashes/

All user password converted hash to md5 password

http://webdevelopingcat.com/encrypt-passwords-using-phpass/

Comment: The link you provide is of a plugin that 1. hasn't been updated for many years and 2. actually provides **less** security by using MD5. `phpass` that is used by WordPress solves may of these issues.