# wordpress secure client portal

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Basically I have a new client that is after the following functionality from her accountancy website:

- A client area in which here existing clients can log into.
- a place within the log in are where clients can access documents
  such as tax    returns etc.

naturally this all needs to be very secure. My question is:

Is there a Wordpress plugin that can achieve this or is their an open source php framework out there that allows me to do this.

I could go through the process myself using php and mysql PDO but apart from encrypting the passwords i am not confident that the security i could program would be adequate. Any recommendations?

Comment: Please note that wordpress uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use) which uses (sometimes unsalted) MD5 for passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Since originally writing this I'm now in agreement with user1744188's answer below. WP-Client has been written specifically for this task, and for me it fills a big gap in the Wordpress market.  The service I've been given is very good and I think it's priced well considering all the features and the resources you get.

It should definitely be noted, however, that the plugin itself is not open source. The main wp-client.php file in the root of the plugin is a big 0.5Mb monster of a file that has been encoded. Every method has been obfuscated and ties into some unencryption method using the  licence key.

So it does what it does but you won't be able to extend or modify it easily.

**Original Answer**

I agree with John - I personally don't think I'd use Wordpress at all for this. However, I did a job not long ago and they sprung this requirement on me right at the end of the build so I had no choice.

I did it using S2 Member and it worked out well. Here's the ongoing thread on how to do it, the developer is a really helpful guy, he's produced a video to help and supported requests.

www.primothemes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=586

Answer (score 2):

You could consider trying WP-Client

It's a Wordpress plugin that was built from the ground up to act as a client portal with the exact functionalities that you describe, plus much more.

http://WP-Client.com

Answer (score 1):

If there are any plugins out there, they probably won't measure up to the amount of security you're looking for.

I would recommend storing all sensitive data outside of the public_html directory so that it is out of grasp for unwanted visitors/robots/etc.

You should also be encrypting all data sent/received with a SSL certificate.

It sounds like you're looking for a lot of functionality- the ability to upload these documents, access them based on users, etc. You may have to code something yourself or find a non-Wordpress solution that works for you. Perhaps you can use login credentials based off of the Wordpress installation...

Answer (score 0):

It's WordPress Plugin that connects with CRM to CMS, Means all your data will store in CRM for better management. you can find Here, They Prodive best solution for **[WordPress Client Portal](https://www.crmjetty.com/wordpress-customer-portal.htm)**.