# Match user password in custom query php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, algorithm

I want to use my WordPress user table in my custom php app.Now the issue is if i try to check password against `md5('password');` - it didn't work. How can i solve the issue.My query is

```
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    SELECT user_login, display_name
    FROM wp_users  
    WHERE user_login=? AND user_pass=?
")){
    /* Bind parameters
         s - string, b - boolean, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, md5($password));
```

How can i match the password to WordPress encrypted password?
Updates with Wp class.

```
function wp_hash_password($password) {
    global $wp_hasher;

    if ( empty($wp_hasher) ) {
        require_once('class-phpass.php');
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    }

    return $wp_hasher->HashPassword( trim( $password ) );
}


if(isset($_POST['login']))
{  


        $username = clean($_POST['login']['username']);
        $password = wp_hash_password($_POST['login']['password']);
echo $password;
exit();
/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'C347278_wordpress2');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{  
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    SELECT user_login, display_name
    FROM wp_users  
    WHERE user_login=? AND user_pass=?
")){
    /* Bind parameters
         s - string, b - boolean, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

    /* Execute it */
    $result = $stmt -> execute();

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if ($result === false) { 
        die("Query failed");
    }

    /* Bind results to variables that will be used within the fetch() loop. */
    $stmt -> bind_result($login_id, $display_name);

    /* Check the number of rows returned. */
    if ($stmt->num_rows != 1) {
        //Login failed
      $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'wrong User name OR Password';

    }

    /* Iterate over the results of the query. */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    { 
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        /* We can use $login_id, $firstname and $lastname cause we binded the result to those variables above. */
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $login_id;
        $_SESSION['SESS_DISP_NAME'] = $display_name;
        //$_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $lastname;
        session_write_close();
       header('Location:http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/app/'.$to); 
        exit();
     }//main if close

      /* Close statement */
      $stmt -> close();
   }

   /* Close connection */
   $mysqli -> close();
}
```

Comment: In newer versions, WordPress does not use md5() anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use

Comment: Maybe this function you are looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

Comment: @jOpacic I am trying to access the password in my custom php app not in WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CheckPassword()` like this :

```
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass, display_name
    FROM wp_users  
    WHERE user_login=?
")){
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $username);

    /* Execute it */
    $result = $stmt -> execute();

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if ($result === false) { 
        die("Query failed");
    }

    /* Bind results to variables that will be used within the fetch() loop. */
    $stmt -> bind_result($id,$login_id,$hash, $display_name);

    /* Check the number of rows returned. */
    if ($stmt->num_rows != 1) {
        //Login failed
      $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Wrong User name OR Password';

    }

    /* Iterate over the results of the query. */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    { 
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
        $check = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);
        if($check){ echo "Password matched" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress native function,

```
$hash = wp_hash_password( $password );
```

Like,

```
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, wp_hash_password($password));
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

`wp_hash_password()` is located in wp-includes/pluggable.php.

Comment: But i haven't wp class.I am trying the code in my custom php app.got my point ?

Comment: ok fine, `wp_hash_password()` is located in wp-includes/pluggable.php. Open that file and get that function use teh same function in your custom app. Hope it helps!

Comment: i import the classes and include the `wp_hash_password()` method, but i got different results for same password.