# What type of encryption is this

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I was wondering if what algorithm is used to crypt a password like below

i tried to unlock it by using md5 but it's not in the md5 format

```
$P$Bvri2AbrQqeA59rh/o0bGE1VGBdBIQ1
```

anyone know how to decrypt it ? And what algorithm is this?
thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but you may want to take a look at here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php, but you cannot decrypt it, you may check it with another string at the best case.

Comment: You need the key and algorithm used in order to decrypt it. As it stands I highly doubt anyone will be able to help you. You can't tell the algorithm used by simply looking at a random string of characters though.

Comment: For starters, MD5 is a **sum** which means even if this was a MD5 string you would never be able to figure out what it came from.

Comment: you can to some extent, rule out what it ISN'T though.  It's not md5 or any variation of SHA.....as those all rely on numeric and alphabetical values.  I see / and $'s in the mix, so it's not one of them.  It very well might be something custom, or a less used format.  As was stated though, if it is something SIMILAR to md5 or SHA, you'll never be able to know what the original source was.

Comment: Looks like more like a hash than an crypted content.

Comment: @MaxiWheat what makes you say that? It could very well be an encrypted string, or a very small chunk of data.

Comment: Thanks for all of you..

Comment: @MaxiWheat Actually it could be both, some encryption methods include all or part of a hash.

Comment: @user2366842 Like Fatih BAKIR said, it looks like the format of a string hashed with http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by tadman, the `$P$B` signature suggests that this is probably a hash generated by the Wordpress password hasher, so it can't be reversed

The WordPress password hasher implements the [Portable PHP password hashing](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) framework, which is used in Content Management Systems like WordPress and Drupal.

You can generate hashes using this encryption scheme at http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hash [generated by WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use) based on the presence of `$P$B`.

You cannot decrypt these by design. The whole point of a robust password hashing system is to make this impractical or impossible.

Answer (score 1):

No one can help you decrypt this, except the people who encrypted this.

Encryption relies on a secret key that is used in conjunction with the encryption method to ensure that only those with the secret key can decrypt the contents. Encryption can also rely on several other factors, including things like a username or personal information.

Furthermore, you have misunderstood the difference between [Checksums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) and [Encrptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). The key difference being that checksums help you verify data, whereas enryptions hide data.