# How to decode encrypted wordpress admin password?

Tags: wordpress, decode

I forgot my WordPress admin password, and I see it in the `phpMyAdmin` file.

But it is in a different form.

How I can decode it to know what my password is?

Is there any tool for decoding passwords?

```
$P$BX5675uhhghfhgfhfhfgftut/0
```

Help me.

Comment: that's a hash, and it can't be "decoded". reset it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of hash does WordPress use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use)

Answer (score 49):

You **can't easily decrypt** the password from the hash string that you see. You should rather **replace** the hash string with a new one from a password that you do know.

There's a good howto here:

https://jakebillo.com/wordpress-phpass-generator-resetting-or-creating-a-new-admin-user/

Basically:

1. generate a new hash from a known password using e.g. http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php, as described in the above link, or any other product that uses the **phpass** library,
2. use your DB interface (e.g. phpMyAdmin) to update the user_pass field with the new hash string.

If you have more users in this WordPress installation, you can also copy the hash string from one user whose password you know, to the other user (admin).

Comment: Right mate, but i just need to simply know what really my password is...but ,hash can't be "decoded". thats the problem....thnx for the reply

Comment: Because if you can decode it as notice, then a hacker will have no difficulty at all :)

Answer (score 36):

just edit wp_user table with your phpmyadmin, and choose MD5 on Function field then input your new password, save it (go button).
[image]

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, as it works.

Comment: My guess is that it was downvoted because, even though it works, it's a terrible recommendation that highlights one of many massive insecurities of the wordpress core

Answer (score 9):

MD5 encrypting is possible, but decrypting is still unknown (to me). However, there are many ways to compare these things.

1. Using compare methods like so:

   ```php
   <?php
     $db_pass = $P$BX5675uhhghfhgfhfhfgftut/0;
     $my_pass = "mypass";
     if ($db_pass === md5($my_pass)) {
       // password is matched
     } else {
       // password didn't match
     }
   ```
2. Only for WordPress users.
   If you have access to your PHPMyAdmin, focus you have because you paste that hashing here: $P$BX5675uhhghfhgfhfhfgftut/0, WordPress `user_pass` is not only MD5 format it also uses `utf8_mb4_cli` charset so what to do?

   That's why I use another Approach if I forget my WordPress password I use

   I install other WordPress with new password :P, and I then go to PHPMyAdmin and copy that hashing from the database and paste that hashing to my current PHPMyAdmin password ( which I forget )

   EASY is use this :

   1. password = "ARJUNsingh@123"
   2. password_hasing = "  $P$BDSdKx2nglM.5UErwjQGeVtVWvjEvD1   "
   3. Replace your $P$BX5675uhhghfhgfhfhfgftut/0  with my
      $P$BDSdKx2nglM.5UErwjQGeVtVWvjEvD1

I USE THIS APPROACH FOR MY SELF WHEN I DESIGN THEMES AND PLUGINS

**WORDPRESS USE THIS**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/

Comment: This is a basic brute force approach, but it is not very effective based on the strength of the password it can take months maybe years to get it right.