# Can't log in to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, password-protection, forgot-password

My friend asked me to help him with [his site on wordpress](http://zhivi-center.ru), he lost the wp admin panel password.

But he didn't loose the mysql login information so sirst i thought about changing the password right through phpmyadmin. I get in phpmyadmin and saw that password looks a little bit strange, like this `$P$BUKCBYLJ.MmLPqlzZTw4P/rLnR.omZ.`

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/) helped me to create password that looks the same as passwords that already existed in mysql db passwords, so i put it in my admin's `user_pass` field.

But i'm still unable to log in.

Actually, when i try to access [/wp-admin/](http://zhivi-center.ru/wp-admin/), i see no standard wordpress login page 
[image: standard wordpress login page]

I see this
 [image: what i see when try to log in]

And when i fail to log in it gives me 401 and shows this page 
 [image: page i see when fail to log in]

Is it ok? What the difference between situations when standard login page shows and when this authentication alert box shows ?

Anyway, all I can think of is:

1) [Online password hasher](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php) gives me wrong password,
2) You see, this authentication box says "please use your control panel password", so i think the site uses some other passwords, not passwords that are in it's db. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this looks 100% dodgy

Comment: Dodgy? What does it mean?

Comment: questionable legality

Comment: Ehm... what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: @Goodsoup It sounds like lucifer63 already has access to the database, so unlikely this is an attempt to hack anything. People forget passwords all the time...

Comment: Oh, he thought i try to hack this site? I'm verry sorry, i thought its obvious that i have access to db if i say i use phpmyhadmin, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing a [*Basic HTTP Authentication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) prompt, which is not part of WordPress - it is being sent by your webserver (likely Apache or Nginx). This provides an additional layer of security against brute force attacks as you need to "log in" to the web server before you can authenticate against WordPress.

The passwords for *Basic Authentication* are typically stored in `.htpasswd` files, and defined either in an `.htaccess` file or your webserver's configuration. Refer to [this guide](http://www.helpdeskhangouts.com/securing-wordpress-admin-basic-http-authentication/) for some more information on how this is set up.

You will need to reset the *Basic Authentication* password in the `.htpasswd` file, or remove it entirely, before you can log into WordPress. Once you access the WordPress login prompt you can use the password that you have set for the user you want to login as. Options for resetting your WordPress password via *SQL*, *phpMyAdmin*, *FTP*, and the *WP CLI* can be found in the article *[Resetting Your Password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password)* on the WordPress site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually i just didn't know for what purpose do `.htaccess` exists) And now i just edited it so that it now doesn't ask user to log in when trying to access `wp-login.php`, and that's all, question is closed) Thanks again