# Wordpress authentication through a C++ program

Tags: php, c++, c, linux, wordpress

**Short version:** I have a server program that I wrote with C++, and a website with Wordpress. I would like to compare the password given by the user to the password stored in Wordpress to log the user in.

**Long version:** At the beginning I thought that [Wordpress uses MD5 hashes due to the password reset mechanism](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password), but it turns out that [Wordpress changes the hash after resetting the password, so it's not MD5 anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use). I have access to the database and I can import the users table. The webserver, the database and the C++ server I wrote run on the same machine with Debian. How can verify a password on C/C++ from Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always assumed wordpress did use [MD5](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) unless you configure it otherwise. The reason why you see the hash changing is probably due to their use of a random salt.

I think your 2 choices boil down to:

- Query the MySQL DB directly
- Shell out to a PHP bootstrap program that includes the skeleton wordpress and pass the username/password via command line to the wordpress API credential check

Comment: But then how do I get over the salt? Every time I hash with wordpress's algorithm I get a different result! How is the comparison done with a salt?

Comment: The salt should be stored with the password. Sorry to be vague but I'm not a wordpress expert. But I believe [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) should help. Look at the example of how they compare the validity of the user input. crypt is a library that comes with Linux so you should be able to call that from C++.