# Reset Wordpress PW in Database

Tags: sql, wordpress, hash

I need to reset a wordpress Password via PHP My Admin. I already tried MD5, and I also tried to upload a PHP file to the base directory and use the wp_has_password() Function and i tried http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4  - but non is working - how can i encrypt a password via PHPMyAdmin?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of hash does WordPress use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use)

Answer (score 0):

[image: please view the image.]

Please view the image and set md5 password