# Wordpress User Password Data as Plaintext / Export Wordpress User Password to Django

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress

I have around 900 users in my wordpress, i am exporting these user data to my new platform that will be using Django.

My question is, how can i export these user's password as plaintext? if i cannot do it, i wanted to store it in "old_password" field in my new database, but i want to know how to "match" text with the old_password? because my plan is that when the user login, i will try to find the user with the same email and the hashed password, but i don't know what type of hashing function Wordpress used and the equivalent of that function in Python Django.

Comment: I really hope you don't have access to your users' plain text passwords... And finding wordpress's hash algorithm takes no more effort than a short google search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of hash does WordPress use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use)

Comment: If you have a look at some of the salted and hashed passwords they may tell you what was used: `algorithm$rounds$hash$salt`

Comment: wordpress uses `wp_hash_password` located in `wp-includes/pluggable.php.`

Comment: Just to be clear, i don't really need the plaintext password if i can't get it, what i do need is the ability to know some plaintext is the same with the hashed wordpress password. Otherwise the users that will be imported to my Django app cannot login with their email and password combination in the old wordpress site.

Comment: @RaymondGoldmanSeger look at the `wp_hash_password` function then see how was implemented, wp does also support `MD5()` I've seen on some sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library, https://github.com/jmoswalt/wp-to-django-users

Basically you add django the capability to re-hash the old wordpress password, so that your old wordpress user can now use their same & old password on the new django site

Within your settings.py file for your django project, add the following:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
'hashers_passlib.phpass',
)
```

then re-hash the password, and you are done.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import get_hasher
hasher = get_hasher('phpass')
user.password = hasher.from_orig(user.password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern password controls are explicitly designed to make deterministic computation of the plain text impossible. The only way, therefore, to determine it is by a "brute force" attack (try hashing all possible passwords until you find one that hashes correctly) or more sophisticated techniques like the use of [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), which reduce compute time but use a lot of storage.

There's some information about WordPress password security in [this article](https://ttmm.io/tech/wordpress-password-hashing/), which might help you, and [this article](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wordpress-password-hashes/#gref) contains PHP code you might repurpose by translating it into Python.

It sounds, though, like the simplest way to proceed would be to validate the users' existing passwords against `old_password` on first login to the new site, then force them (by redirecting them to a specific page) to change their password, clearing the `old_password` field once this is done.

Comment: the problem is, the "old_password" field is empty, i was hoping to fill it with the wordpress hashed password. And when user enter their data in login page. I check the email and then i hash the password with the old_password (if that user have old_password field that is not empty).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise that the export didn't include the old password's hash. Without that there doesn't seem to be much you can do except create a page inside the WordPress site, available only to logged-in users, with a link to the new site's "reset password" page. Since you will have to include some form of identifier so the new site can determine the user who is trying to migrate, you should protect the links by including some verifiable hash that allows the new site to check that the link is genuine.

Comment: i'll try to find a way first, because in wordpress, you can just change the password through phpmyadmin, they use MD5 in the PHPMyAdmin.