# Moving WordPress users to new site and maintaining logins

Tags: php, wordpress

I am migrating a site from WordPress to a new from-scratch site, and want to transfer my users along. Obviously I want them to be able to use the same passwords, but it's not the worst case (small base) if they are forced to reset.

That being said, I can see that WordPress hashes a password like this `$P$BlrNllYDPRevuGVlULvvKzRgLVC3k91` and according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use) they use  [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

I built my own user system using PHP 7 with `password_hash` and `password_verfiy`. I am wondering if it is even possible for me to maintain the current users passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly be possible, but you will need to add some logic to check the legacy password hashes using PHPass. The `password_verify` function cannot magically verify hashes of other formats.

Just check if the hash starts with `$P$` (PHPass uses this prefix). If it does, use the verification methods in PHPass. Otherwise, use the native `password_verify`.

Also, you will want to update the user's stored hash on a successful login, to upgrade it to the new and better hash system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export your staging "users table" and then import it into the new migrated website's database. Like this every user will be able to use the same password as before.