# Hash password and match it with WordPress Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress

We are trying to hash a password entered by user on ASP.NET website.

Hashed password will be matched with the password for same username on a WordPress database.

If the hashes matches, we will copy the user information from WordPress to ASP.NET Website.

We have tried to create the Hash using Blowfish, MD5 and DES but its result does not match with the hash in WordPress database. We have tried the salt from `wp-config.php` file from keys `AUTH_SALT`, `SECURE_AUTH_SALT`, `LOGGED_IN_SALT`, `NONCE_SALT`

I am not sure what exactly WordPress uses for hashing a password.
Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't match by password but by something like email....

Comment: To add to what @EpicKip suggested, you need to confirm if the user is the rightful owner of the email and check that. In case you are persistent, try this [link](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php) and see if this generates the same hash. From the official wordpress site, it looks like `$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);` is used.

Comment: Did you try this [link](http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/)

Comment: It uses phpass. See here for c#implementation. https://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp

Comment: In particular, this documentation page will be useful: https://docs.zer7.com/cryptsharp/html/ce06b69c-fa52-a499-bcb5-5f4e39d99bf9.htm

Comment: @EpicKip of course first it is being matched by email but then we need to match the password hash as well

Comment: @Oasa I have tried it already, the problem with this tool is that every time I click on `Hash this phrase`, it generates a different hash for same string.

Comment: @kamalpreet That's... not good. Only match on email never go match on password. I use a different password in most places... what then?

Comment: @kamalpreet exactly, what if the user has different passwords. Like I said you should just verify the email and proceed with the integration. However for the purpose of solving the riddle, let me also check the docs. May be the hash is different because the salt changes at each instance is stored within the hash. Perhaps thats why you are unable to get the result you wanted. Are you comparing both hashes via a string/text compare? If yes, it wont be same.

Comment: Just as we suspected, a random salt is added everytime. I hope this answers your question. Look [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dd6da701b286579819cd6aa518aa2d7018efd759/wp-includes/class-phpass.php)

Comment: @spender I was just trying with the c# implementation. But the salts which I copied from WP are giving error when used in this implementation. Error is "Invalid salt"

Comment: @kamalpreet That sounds a lot like a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Why not ask one?

Comment: @EpicKip I believe the questioner means that the they are locating the user account by userID, and want to validate the password against the WordPress user database as part of an account migration exercise.

Comment: @ben then if they won't match he's obviously using different salt/hash :)

Comment: @EpicKip that was the question! "What hash should I use".

Comment: @ben https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use then it's a dupe

Comment: @EpicKip yes, it is. So vote to close.

Comment: OP needs to use `CheckPassword($plain_password, $hash_password))`

Comment: @ben was on phone voted to close now. Should begone soon