# Why my wordpress changes my password?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installed and when I refresh my page, my password in phpmyadmin changes. Why? How can I change this and log in?

Comment: Which page are you refreshing? The Wordpress home page or phpmyadmin? Your WordPress installation should not have priviliges to change the user database of the server it is running on. It should store the WordPress users in the database you created for WordPress.

Comment: my-page.com/wp-admin or homepage, then my password changes

Comment: So you log in to your WordPress site, see the homepage and then if you refresh you are logged back out and can't see the homepage anymore unless you log back in. Am I understanding correctly? Are you logging on as the WordPress user you created when you first installed WordPress on the server.

Comment: nope, I don't know my password, I want to change it in my phpmyadmin but when I change password and then try to log in, wordpress says that my password is incorrect

Comment: So when I try this out, the issue that I have is that WordPress encrypts the password. Passwords for regular users are stored encrypted, so in the database they look like: $Q@B0PYnbBwr5Tgw9LsWP45HmPT0ub2zm0. When you try to change the password directly from phpmyadmin, you are storing an unencrypted password that looks like: my_password. When you try to login in, it takes your input, encrypts it, and compares it against my_password. This all goes on behind the scenes, but it explains why your password doesn't work. I am looking into how to fix this, but thought I should let you know the cause.

Comment: Just use the "forgot my password" link in the wp-admin login page?

Comment: @GenericGuy, please consider undeleting your answer or adding a new one - it was really good & definitely helpful for other users who they don't know their username. zaph was just being overzealous in educating everyone about security (whether it was relevant or not :) ) He didn't realise MD5 was how WP's own instructions tell you to update the db. Just make it clear that you're using terminology that the OP would understand as an example. (BTW I'd actually come back to upvote it to counteract the downvote, I was out of votes at the time).

Comment: @FluffyKitten I wish I could do this in a pm... but since SO doesn't have I guess I will add to this huge chain of comments. Thanks, I appreciate you coming back to say this. As someone just out of college and trying to get back into helping on SO, getting ranted at by someone with 90k rep is disheartening. But I am glad to see that people like you are on here as well :D!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your password is *supposed* to change when it is being saved to the database.
    
   As Loop Me said, it gets "encrypted"* (see note below) when you set your password in the Admin. This is for security - Passwords should *never* be stored in plain text. Otherwise anyone who gains access to the database can see everyone's passwords.
2. **Don't *ever* mess around directly in the database unless there is *absolutely no alternative***... one wrong change can break your entire site, and could make it impossible to recover if you can't undo it.

As you've been manually trying to change your password in the database, you will need to reset it through Wordpress so that it is "encrypted"* properly so that Wordpress will recognise it.

Stay away from the database! :-) You know your username, so you can use the "Lost your Password?" link on the login page and let Wordpress update the database for you. 
If you need it, the page that Loop Me referenced also has instructions how to do it this way: https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_the_automatic_emailer

---

*Note on hashing (as used in Wordpress) vs encryption:

Even though Loop Me called it "encrypted", the password actually gets `hashed`. The term "encrypt" - although inaccurate - is being used here for *simplicity only* to illustrate what is happening to the plain-text password; most people are familiar with the concept of encryption whereas "hashing" is not as well known.

*Hashing is a one-way function from which the original can not be recovered. Encryption is a two-way function with a key from which the original can be recovered with use of the key* - ref @zaph

However the point behind both answers is still valid - **the Wordpress database does not store plain text passwords and you cannot just add a plain-text password into it.**

Comment: Wow, "hashing which is different and less secure than actual encryption" even got an eye-roll and head in hands from my wife! (I am not making that up!) Yes they are different and it is not possible to compare their security since they are completely different and used for different purposes thus hashing is **not** less secure than encryption. That said, encryption should not be used for password verifiers in databases. Using an MD5 hash of a password a verifier is little better than saving the plain password. Specifically NIST recommends PBKDF2 and a CPU utilization of ~100ms.

Comment: @zaph, as I keep saying - that level of information is *way* beyond the level of the OP and is irrelevant to the issue they are having.

Comment: Consider future readers, that is the main point of SO. Also consider correcting the incorrect information, especially in the note.

Comment: @zaph - How would you like me to say it to someone who doesn't know they can't type a plain text passwords directly into a database? And that isn't sarcasm, I honestly don't know how to explain such concepts in a meaningful way to someone with so little understanding. They won't even know what hashing is, so calling it encryption is just the simplest way to explain in a way they'd understand. And again, the Wordpress database uses MD5 so that's what they *have* to use.

Comment: Notes: 1. [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207875/451475) The WordPress password hasher implements the Portable PHP password hashing framework, which is used in Content Management Systems like WordPress and Drupal.

They used to use MD5 in the older versions 2.[frameworkgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23774030/451475) To prevent breaking backwards compatibility, MD5-hashed passwords stored in the database are still valid. When a user logs in with such a password, WordPress detects MD5 was used, rehashes the password using the more secure method, and stores the new hash in the database.

Comment: @zaph sorry, I don't understand the relevance of that to my comment? I have no mention in MD5 in my answer, so I'm not sure how updating it with information about backward compatibility would help?

Comment: The MD5 mention is in your comment above: "Wordpress database uses MD5" and that is essentially incorrect..

Comment: @zaph The instructions on the Wordpress Codex page (as linked to in the other answer) say to use MD5 to update the password directly in the database via phpadmin. That was what they were trying to do, not update it via code. So anyway, would you like to suggest how to explain about encryption in my note about how the use of "encrypt" was for simplicity?

Comment: In answer to "How would you like me to say " my suggestion: Answer the question simply with the correct terminology, explaining the terminology as needed. Then provide background information such as the Wordpress instructions and adding the auto update information. Leaving the reader to think that MD5 is actually used and is an acceptable verifier. Write the answer for future readers, they vastly outnumber the single requester.

Comment: WRT "Your password is supposed to change automatically" an explanation of the auto update would be of great help in understanding what is happening.

Comment: @zaph I don't intend including instructions on how to update the database directly as it was addressed in the other answer, and also is a bad idea & totally unnecessary in the case. My answers was telling them how *not* to do it that way. The only reference I need to make to hashing/encryption is why the password looked different to what they entered via the admin when they saw it in the db, As I said they won't understand what "hashing" is, and its not really relevant in my answer other than explaining WP automatically changes the password.

Comment: Your Answer, your choice.

Comment: @zaph ah but I need to get it right for future users, and my attempts so far to explain encryption (as a term people understand) vs hashing (as one that many don't) have fell short of accurate simplicity...

Comment: Then explain: Hashing is a one-way function from which the original can not be recovered. Encryption is a two-way function with a key from which the original can be recovered with use of the key.

Comment: @zaph totally irrelevant to the answer and OP, but I've added it as suggested, as you think it will help future users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will show you how to fix your problem: https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin

The problem is that WordPress uses MD5 hashing to store the passwords. So when you put your password into the database without passing it through a hashing function, the passwords won't match. To do so follow the steps in the article or those below:

1. Select User to edit
2. Change the password
3. Select MD5 from the drop menu to the left of the password
4. Save the edits to the user
5. Login to your WordPress site

**NOTE** Only do this as a last resort. if you can, change the password through email.

Comment: I am doing it, but then my password changes automatically. I do not know why. Maybe virus or sth like this?

Comment: So you go into the users database for wordpress, edit the user password, select MD5, and then press go at the bottom to save. The password should appear to change when you look at it (since its been encrypted), and then that password doesn't work for the username when you try to login to wordpress as that user? This would be weird, but you do for sure have privileges to edit the database correct?

Comment: MD5 is neither encryption nor a secure hash for a paswsword verifier.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph No-one is disputing how insecure the hash is... we're just trying to explain as simply as possible to the OP that the password isn't stored in plain text in the database. They appear to think that they have a virus because it's not the same in to the database as what they entered....! With that level of understanding, I doubt they'd understand what "hash means :-)

Comment: Do you also provide stepladders to help people jump off bridges? That is what you are doing by suggesting MD5 or any hash primitive. The only real difference is that end users are being put at risk in potentially large numbers. All for some rep!

Comment: True about understanding what a hash is, right here there is an M.Sc. in Computer Science who doesn't! But that is no reason to put innocent users at risk.

Comment: @zaph "That is what you are doing by suggesting MD5 or any hash primitive. "... No one is recommending MD5, hashing or anything else here, That's just the option they need for Wordpress to work. We're just trying to explain to someone why they can't put a plaintext password directly into the Wordpress database and expect it to work!

Comment: @zaph as I said in my answer, I was referencing Loop Me's comment - I know the difference, its just not relevant here in the least. I know the value of keeping things consistent & simple when trying to help someone who doesn't understand the basics. It is honestly not going to put this user at any risk if they expected the password to be plain text in the first place! However, just the sake of completeness and anyone else who may need these answers - as unlikely as that is (I hope...) - I've added a note to my answer to clarify.