# Empty set is returned when set condition for password

Tags: php, mysql

Im quite new in mysql

I have inserted values into my table **customer**

```
INSERT INTO customer(f_name, l_name, mobilehp, username, password)
VALUES
('Ahmad', 'Ali', '013-5404997', 'A_Ali', SHA('something'));
```

Then I inserted a condition,

```
select customer_id, f_name FROM customer WHERE password=SHA('something');
```

However the query returned empty set which is weird when it supposed to display customer_id and f_name. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use SHA for "encrypting" passwords.

Comment: oh,  then  what should I use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020448/which-method-to-use-to-encrypt-passwords-in-mysql-database/46021602

Comment: @MursyidNasir https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: or [ref](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will be looking into these

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why is this even tagged with PHP, but does not contain a single line of PHP code?

Answer (score -1):

Do not use sha1 for passwords. Use password_hash or other crypto algorithm. sha1 is unsecure.

```
select customer_id, f_name, password FROM customer WHERE f_name = 'Ahmad';
```

Then check password.

See comments in links
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify

Comment: Even if SHA1 should not be used, this does not explain why the two queries do not work