# Importing Wordpress Users into Firebase authentication

Tags: wordpress, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am in process of migrating my Wordpress site into Firebase. I have managed to export my Wordpress users into the following JSON format below (as described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth))

I believe WordPress uses MD5 but I am struggling to import the WordPress passwords into Firebase. I am unsure what the passwordHash value needs to be? Does anyone have any idea?

```
  {
    "users": [
      {
        "localId": "11",
        "passwordHash": "",
        "email": "test@icloud.com",
        "createdAt": "1515666546293",
        "displayName": "test name"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress no longer uses MD5. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207875/5861618) it now implements [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). Although other posts ([like this one](http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/) for example) claim that it uses [Blowfish](https://www.schneier.com/academic/blowfish/).

Under the `passwordHash` field you must set the hashed password that you got from WordPress (`$P$BXb4SCf11vB9pPFJFbkDLzDqVq89ra/` for example). The hashing algorithm is specified on the Firebase CLI when importing the data:

```
firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo=BCRYPT
```

Notice that I've used **BCRYPT** as the hashing algorithm. That's because [it is based on Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). I can't assure that Firebase Auth will recognize these WordPress passwords.

If it doesn't, then I would suggest that you import the accounts, passing a random String under the `passwordHash` field and then [email your users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) explaining that your site is going through a migration process thus they will need to reset their passwords before logging in again.

Comment: I had already made plans to go down the route of resetting user passwords but will try the hashing algorithm approach first. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Have you been successful importing the user data from WordPress into Firebase using this approach?

Comment: How was the import, successful? @londonfed

Comment: @mef_  My plan was to import all users and then send them a password reset notification. But the project got cancelled.