# What algorithm does wordpress use to hash password?

Tags: wordpress, hash, passwords

I am trying to export users from a wordpress website to a non-wordpress webiste.
I have all the encrypted passwords, and i want to implement the same algorithm use by wordpress to let the current users login with the same credentials.
I saw something like [this](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php) but if i try different times, it get me different results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What type of hash does WordPress use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045988/what-type-of-hash-does-wordpress-use)

Answer (score 1):

Standard WordPress is using a MD5 Hashing algorithm according to their Documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/