# Admin password changed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a site using wordpress 8.1. Working on it for a month. I am the only admin and no one else has access to it. Also, there is a maintenance module activated on frontend. Today I was not able to login to admin panel. I went directly to database and using mysql query updated the password to the same one I had before, and I noticed that the hash changed! Now looking into what could have happened:

The password was **Dlz5Kw!6fKz6PC!**

The hash in user_pass cell before reset was **$P$B8cdsIzBO6XtR4ivHNNyoPfYrxkPuG1**

After running following mysql command to re-enter the password:

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = MD5('Dlz5Kw!6fKz6PC!') WHERE `user_login` = 'super@mysite.yes';
```

The hash in the user_pass cell became **3fd782c7917cb5823e71fd3d0b632ac1**

Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: That is because the first one **$P$B8cdsIzBO6XtR4ivHNNyoPfYrxkPuG1** is the [salted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252873/223934) `md5` password, which WordPress saves inside the database.

Comment: **$P$** indicates that it is salted, and **B** after that means it is hashed with Blowfish, the next 8 characters (i think) (8cdsIzBO) are the salt and the rest is the hash. You can read more about MD5 hash in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045988/10497022).

Comment: Thanks for info but my main concern is why it happened?

Comment: Sorry. It is not clear to me if your concern is why you lost access? or why the user_pass cell is not the same as previous? I don't know why you couldn't gain access with your credentials. But! If you just use the default MD5 in the database, **once you login**, WordPress should rehash automatically using `PHPass`. If you don't see **$P$B**, maybe the password was not hashed using the `PHPass` utility.